# Retrieving value using .loc and dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have three DataFrames. One for daily FX prices `d_fx`, one for daily NAV values `d`, and one for reference data `m`. Examples below:

```
               EUR     GBP  USD
date                           
2012-01-01  1.2961  1.5543  1.0
2012-01-02  1.2934  1.5514  1.0
2012-01-03  1.3050  1.5649  1.0
2012-01-04  1.2943  1.5620  1.0

                 date           Assets      
 BUTBERI BH Equity 2012-01-01   14.32000
                   2012-01-02   14.32000
                   2012-01-03   14.32000
                   2012-01-04   14.34000
                   2012-01-05   14.34000
 JGGFLEU LX Equity 2012-01-01  19.88656
                   2012-01-02  20.01639
                   2012-01-03  19.99365
                   2012-01-04  20.31770
                   2012-01-05  20.35174
 ICEPROB FH Equity 2012-01-01 NaN
                   2012-01-02 NaN
                   2012-01-03 NaN
                   2012-01-04 NaN
                   2012-01-05 NaN

                   FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS_CRNCY
 BUTBERI BH Equity                     USD
 ICEPROB FH Equity                     EUR
 JGGFLEU LX Equity                     EUR
```

I am trying set columns in DataFrame `d` using .loc, but not successfully. Using the following:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
d.loc[idx[:,:], 'FX_price'] = 
                               d_fx.loc[d.index.get_level_values(1),
                                  m.loc[d.index.get_level_values(0)].values]
```

The script completes without error but all of the values in `FX_price` are `NaN`. Is there a better way to do this? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Many thanks in advance.
`
**AMENDED Dataframes**

Comment: It's really hard to reproduce your problem because you have not provided enough information about your dataframes. `d.index.get_level_values` tells that you use multiindex which is hidden from everybody else but you. Can you provide the code to generate sample dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename` by column `FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS_CRNCY` with [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
d = d.rename(index=m['FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS_CRNCY'], level=0)
print (d)
                Assets
    date              
USD 2012-01-01   14.32
    2012-01-02   14.32
    2012-01-03   14.32
    2012-01-04   14.34

d['FX_price'] = d_fx.lookup(d.index.get_level_values(1), d.index.get_level_values(0))
print (d)
                Assets  FX_price
    date                        
USD 2012-01-01   14.32       1.0
    2012-01-02   14.32       1.0
    2012-01-03   14.32       1.0
    2012-01-04   14.34       1.0
```

Comment: I may have oversimplified. I have amended the DataFrames above. If I rename the index doesn't the reduce the index down to 'EUR' and 'USD' only? d.index has 3 levels but m['FUND_TOTAL_ASSETS_CRNCY'] has only two values.

Comment: Actually, this works for me with some modification. df.lookup was what I needed. Thanks!